# ggplot, boxplots spacing and stat_summary position

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I've tried various combination of options without success.
I would like to:

1) change the fill-color of the means rectangles to be white

2) position each mean (rectangle) at the centre of its own boxplot

3) increase the horizontal space between the 4 groups (not between individual box) of boxplots

```
  boxp <- ggplot(df[df$QG=="INV",], aes(qID, Val, fill=Cond)) +
      geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA) +
      stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, colour = "black") +
      labs(x = "Questions", y="Values", title = "Question subgroup", colour = "Conditions")
  boxp
```

[image]

reproducible example with mtcars

```
boxp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, disp, fill=vs)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = NA) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, colour = "black") +
  labs(x = "Questions", y="Values", title = "Question subgroup", colour = "Conditions")
boxp

mtcars <- mutate_at(mtcars, c("carb", "gear", "vs"), as.factor)
```

Comment: can you post a reproducible example of your data please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5784757

Comment: added with mtcars.